# Redirect wget output to perl script input

Tags: linux, wget

Is it possible to have the output of a wget redirected as input of a perl script (i guess it doesn't matter if it's perl or not, just a generic command). Something like:

```
perl perl_command.pl < wget http://some.cool.site.com/data.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

In `bash`:

```
perl perl_command.pl < (wget http://some.cool.site.com/data.txt)
```

Comment: @Konerak fails after a while with the error: Segmentation fault